# Get X and Y Coordinate From Annotation iOS

Tags: ios, annotations

This should be simple enough, but I'm just getting use to the mapkit framework. What I need to do here is get the coordinates of a selected annotation (to save them). Im not too concerned with the core data side of things. I would really just like to retrieve the coordinates from a selected annotation. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be any good resources on stack overflow for this topic.

I already have the code set up to get the annotation title of a selected annotation, so most of the leg work should already be done here. There has to be something similar I can do to find the coordinate of that same annotation.

```
[DataSource sharedInstance].pointFromMapView = [self.mapView.selectedAnnotations objectAtIndex:([self.mapView.selectedAnnotations count]) -1];
    [DataSource sharedInstance].annotationTitleFromMapView = [DataSource sharedInstance].pointFromMapView.title;
```

The code above will retrieve the annotation title. There has to be a way I can use this code to retrieve the coordinate as well. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[DataSource sharedInstance].pointFromMapView.coordinate` to get the coordinate for the annotation.

Comment: I got to that, but I'm still a little confused on how to actually get the data from it. Do I need to set up a CLLocationCoordinate2D object?

Comment: You mean getting the latitude and longitude of the `CLLocationCoordinate2D` object? Or are you able to get those values but they are both empty?

Comment: I need to be able to save the annotated coordinate, but I get an error when trying to store [DataSource sharedInstance].pointFromMapView in a MKPointAnnotation object. To start, I'd just like to log [DataSource sharedInstance].pointFromMapView.coordinate to see what is there. I also get errors on that as well. But to answer your question, I don;

Comment: I don't know how to get the values*

Comment: I think I just answered my question using .latitude and .longitude. I'll be posting my code shorty. I appreciate the starting point! And for the most part the answer.